# find substring in string but not follow orders

Tags: mysql

I got list of data like this

| Data | Set |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3,4 | A |
| 2,3,4 | B |
| 1,4 | C |
| 2,4 | D |

These scenario in mysql should match:

| Find Data | Matched Set |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2 | A |
| 1,4 | A , C |
| 2,4 | A, B, D |
| 1,3,4 | A |

**Luckily that the lists from Data is ALWAYS INT and sort by ascending.**

Comment: you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and think about normalisation

Comment: @nbk: I know, but following multiselect type of magento2, they stored the data like that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only looking for one of your "Find Data" results in a given query, you can use LIKE for this.  But you need some delimiter before and after each number for that to work; I'm going to use `;`.  So to find "1,2":

```
select group_concat(Set order by Set) as 'Matched Set'
from list_of_data
where concat(';',replace(Data,',',';;'),';') LIKE '%;1;%;2;%';
```

Here we change each row's data; for instance, `1,3,4` becomes `;1;;3;;4;`.  Then search for the delimited numbers you are trying to find, with `%` allowing other numbers before or after each one.  If you cannot translate the `1,2` to this form in your code, you can do it in your query, like:

```
LIKE concat('%;',replace('1,2',',',';%;'),';%')
```